# mountPath property in the Volume Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volume

I am learning about Volumes in the `Kubernetes`.
I understood the concept of Volume and types of volume.
But, I am confused about the `mouthPath` property. Following my `YAML` file:

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata:
  name: nginx-alpine-volume
spec:   

containers: 
  - name: nginx 
    image: nginx:alpine 
    volumeMounts: 
      - name: html 
        mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
        readOnly: true 
    resources:
  - name: html-updater 
    image: alpine 
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"] 
    args: 
      - while true; do date >> /mohit/index.html;sleep 10; done 
    resources:
    volumeMounts: 
      - name: html 
        mountPath: /mohit
  volumes: 
  - name: html 
    emptyDir: {}
```

Question: What is the use of the `mountPath` property. Here, I am using one pod with two containers. Both containers have different `mounPath` values.

### Update:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the mount path as the directory where you are attaching or mounting the files or system

While your actual volume is **emptyDir**

What basically the idea is there to both container have different mount path

as both containers need to use different folders

While as your volume is single name html so locally from volume both container pointing or using the different folders

both containers manage the different files at their mounting point (or folder)

so mount path is a point or directly where your container will be managing files.

Empty dir : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

if you see this example: https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx/blob/master/wordpress-deployment.yaml

it has the same two containers with mount path and **emptydir** volume

what i am doing is attaching the Nginx configuration file, to the container so Nginx will use that configuration file which i am mounting from outside to the container.

My config file stored inside **configmap** or **secret**.

Comment: Thank you Harsh. So, mountPath is a file directory or way to access emptyDir (volume). For example: if I need to access a network location on my Windows laptop so I can mount this location and whenever I want to access this network location, I can use it by the mount.

Comment: Also, I added an image of my understanding. is this correct?

Comment: I also asked a different question related to a link which you have provided. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797029/communicate-between-containers-in-the-same-pod-using-a-shared-volume

Comment: yes you are right, empty dir create the directory on Node basically when you are running the worker nodes or on which it's scheduled.

Comment: Thank you Harsh. last thing: if I create a new file in the /mohit (html-updater), I can access it another container nginx (and vice versa). Is this correct?

Comment: yes as you have made diagram having the same file system. so if the container is backed by same filesystem or mounted path it will.

Comment: if you have on mount as ready only that you can not write it