# Communicate Between Containers in the Same Pod Using a Shared Volume

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to learn Kubernetes. I was going through a link but not able to understand one thing.

URL: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

Mentioned in the doc:

> Notice that the second container writes the index.html file in the root directory of the nginx server.

How is this HTML file created in the root directory of the Nginx server? As we are executing this command in the different container i.e. debian-container.

Comment: Both containers share/use the same volume. One writes to it and the other is able to read it. Imagine if you and I have a shared folder on Drive/Dropbox (or wherever). When I put some file in that folder, you'll be able to see it and open it. The same applies for those containers.

Comment: Agreed. That's the concept of the common shared location. My question is related to the mentioned statement: how debian Container created the "index.html" file in the nginx root directory.

Comment: Because of the `mountPath`. You have a volume which you want to share between containers and for each container you decide where you want to mount that volume. For Debian container it's mounted under `/pod-data` and for Nginx container it's under `/usr/share/nginx/html` (default root directory). Whichever file is created in `/pod-data` in Debian container, it'll be accessible in `/usr/share/nginx/html` in Nginx container (and vice versa).

Comment: Search for [sidecar container examples](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/kubernetes-learn-sidecar-container-pattern-6d8c21f873d) and play around with them.

Comment: @StefanGolubović, could you please post an answer based on your comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example from the link you posted you have:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

You have two containers which share a volume, named `shared-data`. Each container decides where does it want to mount the volume:

- `nginx-container` is mounting it to `/usr/share/nginx/html` (also known as Nginx's default root directory)
- `debian-container` is mounting it to `/pod-data`.

Since shared volume is like a shared directory on a computer or in a cloud, everything present in the volume is available in both containers under the `mountPath` path.

In the example, the `debian-container` writes `index.html` file to a shared space, which can then be used by `nginx-container`.

This is a well-known pattern in Kubernetes, called Sidecar Container Pattern. In this case `debian-container` is a sidecar container. It extends and enhances the functionality of main container (`nginx-container`) - provides `index.html` file in this simple example.

---

Resources:

- [Kubernetes — Learn Sidecar Container Pattern](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/kubernetes-learn-sidecar-container-pattern-6d8c21f873d)
- [The Sidecar Pattern](https://www.magalix.com/blog/the-sidecar-pattern)